# Choosing optimal multithreading model for new Kafka consumer API

Tags: java, multithreading, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let me first describe my use-case.

I have topics [ *T1* ... *Tn* ] to which the Kafka consumer(s) need to subscribe to. For each topic, all the data passing though it are logically similar. Let's assume data in different topics don't have any correlation. But once consumed, all the data irrespective of their topics receive the same treatment, i.e. they are fed to Elasticsearch using bulkprocessor api. ES is set up as multi-node cluster.

The kafka consumer [javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) mentions two different multithreading approaches. I'm leaning towards the first approach, i.e. **One Consumer Per Thread** model. Assuming #partitions / topic = *p*, I'll have *p* consumer threads for each topic. So, in total there will be *n.p* threads. If I've independent bulkprocessor attached to each of these threads, then I can choose to control *committed position* manually. It'll save me from data loss in case bulkprocessor fails. But the downside is, number of bulkprocessors might become too high and that might slow down elasticsearch ingestion.

The other approach I'm thinking, is to have only one thread per topic, so each thread listens to *p* partitions and writes to one bulk processor. In that case I've to use auto-commit for offsets, and I might lose data for bulkprocessor failure.

I'd like to know which approach is better, or is there a 3rd approach, better than both of these?

> Kafka v0.9.0.x and ES v2.3.x